# django-haystack + Whoosh SearchQuerySet().all() always None

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using:

django: 1.9.7
django-haystack: 2.5.0
whoosh: 2.7.4

search_index.py

```
class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    last_name= indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name')
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='first_name')
    def get_model(self):
        return User
    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

user_text.txt

```
{{ object.last_name }}
```

in the views.py i try:
`SearchQuerySet().count() => returns 0`
`SearchQuerySet().all() => returns None`

I've read about some issues with the latest Whoosh implementation in django-haystack but i'm not sure if the problem is in my code

Comment: Have you run `manage.py rebuild_index`?

Comment: Yes , i've changed the structure of the ProfileIndex multiple times (with different model_attr ) , changed the template file , but still no change

Comment: When you rebuild the index, it should tell you how many items were indexed. What does it say there?

Comment: It says 5 (i have 5 objects for the User model)

Comment: Where exactly is your index template (full path)? The most likely issue is that it's in the wrong place.

Comment: templates/search/indexes/<name_of_app>/user_text.txt  
(templates is on the same level as manage.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer here:

[Django Haystack & Whoosh Search Working, But SearchQuerySet Return 0 Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378644/django-haystack-whoosh-search-working-but-searchqueryset-return-0-results/40380881#40380881)

There is a bug in Django-Haystack with Woosh that means if you use an Ngram or EdgeNGram field SearchQuerySet().count() and SearchQuerySet().all().count() will always return 0 unless you specify a filter.

e.g.

```
SearchQuerySet().all().count()
>> 0

SearchQuerySet().all().exclude(content='thisshouldnotmatchanything').count()
>> 14 [the total number of indexed objects]
```