# Django Haystack & Whoosh Search Working, But SearchQuerySet Return 0 Results

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-haystack, whoosh

**Edit: More info at bottom of post...**

Original Question:

I seem to be having the same problem as in this (unresolved) question:
[django-haystack + Whoosh SearchQuerySet().all() always None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913004/django-haystack-whoosh-searchqueryset-all-always-none)

I've set up Haystack with Whoosh on my Django project and all was working fine at first (SearchQuerySet used to return results), but after an aborted attempt to create a new custom search form (rolled back from git) it appears that indexing and the original search page still all work fine, but now SearchQuerySet() always returns 0 results!

Running:

```
manage.py rebuild_index --verbosity=2
```

Correctly shows:

```
Indexing 14 assets
    indexed 1 - 14 of 14 (worker PID: 1234).
```

These indexed assets can then all be correctly searched on from the original search form.

However, opening a Django shell and running:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
SearchQuerySet().all().count()
```

Always returns `0`!

Relevant `pip freeze`:

- Python 3.5.2
- Django 1.9.3
- django-haystack 2.5.0
- Whoosh 2.7.4

/myapp/search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Asset

class AssetIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.NgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    asset_description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='asset_description')
    manufacturer = indexes.CharField(model_attr='asset_manufacturer')

    def get_model(self):
        return Asset

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.exclude(content='foo')

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

/myapp/templates/search/indexes/myapp/asset_text.txt:

```
{{ object.asset_description }}
{{ object.asset_details }}
{{ object.asset_manufacturer }}
{{ object.asset_model }}
... etc.
```

/myapp/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    ....
]
```

**EDIT:**

So digging in the Haystack source code I've found out where the 0 is coming from, but not why!

/myvenv/Lib/site-packages/hackstack/query.py

```
class SearchQuerySet(object):
    ...

    def __len__(self):
        if self._result_count is None:
            self._result_count = self.query.get_count()

        # Some backends give weird, false-y values here. Convert to zero.
        if not self._result_count:
            self._result_count = 0

    # This needs to return the actual number of hits, not what's in the cache.
    return self._result_count - self._ignored_result_count

    ....
```

Changing the `0` to any int makes SearchQuerySet always return that int, but I still don't know why `if not self._result_count` would be true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this a bug in haystack that has already been reported but has yet to be addressed:

https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1021

Unfortunately if the "text" index field is Ngram or EdgeNgram `SearchQuerySet().count()` and `SearchQuerySet().all().count()` will return `0` unless you specify a filter, e.g. `SearchQuerySet().all().exclude(content='thisshouldnotmatchanythingintheindex').count()` returns the total number of indexed objects.